# pass parameters with OnServerClick vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am really new in VB and It is hard to get my head around it especially working with non-MVC projects, so i wish i can find my answer here.

I want to pass arguments with the OnServerClick the code below is the html code:

`<a id="Anchor1"  OnServerClick="LogIn"   runat=server> Click Me </a>`

and the method in the server is below:

```
 Protected Sub LogIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   e.value
   End Sub
```

I want to pass parameters(args) to the LogIn method??

I don't want to use any VB or razor buttons or anchor tags i want to use the html tags with the onserverclick attribute. is that possible??

thank you in advance.

Comment: What you are intended to pass as parameter, so that you can retrieve as `e.value`? If you are interesting in getting `"Anchor1"` in `LogIn`, then i can definitely help you.

Comment: tell me how can i pass the id, but that is not really what i want. i want to pass any parameters like the word `edit` or anything

Comment: You have used a hidden field, and use `Request.Form[]` to get those value, but the method i am going to show to get `id` , is basically  reading `sender` object, and get the value, Are you still interested for code?

Comment: i have updated my code , it is working, let me know, if you need anything other than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add custom attribute to aspx `<a>` like this.

`<a id="Anchor1"  OnServerClick="LogIn"   runat="server" customdata="hello"> Click Me </a>`

And get that value in `LogIn`.

```
Protected Sub LogIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim myButton = CType(sender, HtmlAnchor)
    Dim valuepassedfromUI = myButton.Attributes("customdata")
    Dim buttonID = myButton.ClientID
End Sub
```

, See the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: that is not what I really need but it is the perfect work around. thanks a million